# C# query to fetch row based on foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, linq

I have two tables:

Component

[image: Component]

and Component Profile

[image: ComponentProfile]

`ComponentId` is a foreign key to Component Profile

What I want to do is fetch All Component for a specific Business entity Id and then display all component Profiles for those Component ids from C#

I have been able to retrieve all components for a given business entity id

```
var component = context.Components.Where(i => i.BusinessEntityId == businessEntityId ).ToList();
```

I want to retrieve distinct component ids so that I can get all Component Profiles from it. How do i achieve this, Component Id is unique for each Profile. I am hoping that once I get distinct component Ids

```
foreach (var componentObject in componentObjects)
{
    var componentId = componentObject.Id;
    var componentProfile= context.ComponentProfiles.Where(i => i.ComponentId.Value == componentId);

    if (componentProfile != null)
    {
        result.Add(componentProfile.Map<Libraries.Entities.ComponentProfile>());
    }
}
```

What is an easy way to do this?

Comment: In your component query, have you tried changing your where clause by replacing the `ToList()` with `Select(c => new { c.ComponentId }).Distinct()`?  This should give you distinct ComponentIds.

Comment: Yes.. but basically i want to tie the business entity id and this together

Comment: Havent found how to achieve both

Comment: How about adding the business entity to the Select like so `Select(c => new { c.ComponentId, c.BusinessEntityId }).Distinct()`?

Comment: That is not working. Shows syntax error

Comment: Oops!  You may have to add ToList() at the end of the Select.  So `Select(c => new { c.ComponentId, c.BusinessEntityId }).Distinct().ToList()`.

Comment: How do you want to tie multiple business entity ids to the one distinct component id you are retrieving?

Comment: Thats a good point.. But there should be some way in which i can achieve this. just to display component profiles filtered on component ids for one business entity ids

Comment: Now that I think about it, won't `component` just contain a single business entity id and you already know that - it is `businessEntityId` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution combines all the code into a single Linq query.

```
var context = GetCoreDbEntityContext(businessEntityId);
var result = context.Components
    .Where(i => i.BusinessEntityId == businessEntityId)    // find relevant components
    .Select(c => new { c.ComponentId, c.BusinessEntityId })    // isolate the fields needed
    .Distinct()    // find distinct combinations of fields
    .Join(    // inner join distinct combinations with ComponentProfiles
        context.ComponentProfiles,    // table or list to inner join with
        c => c.ComponentId,    // key selector from Components used in join
        p => p.ComponentId,    // key selector from ComponentProfiles used in join
        (c, p) => new {    // select individual fields or table(s) as needed
            c.BusinessEntityId,    // individual component business entity ID
            c,    // all Component fields
            p    // all ComponentProfile fields
        })
    .Select(r => r.p)    // (optional) reduce columns to only ComponentProfiles
    .ToList();

return result;    // contains list of ComponentProfiles
```

Alternatively, if you only need the componentProfiles, you could do this.

```
var context = GetCoreDbEntityContext(businessEntityId);
var result = context.ComponentProfiles
    .Where(p => context.Components
        .Where(i => i.BusinessEntityId == businessEntityId)    // find relevant components
        .Any(c => c.ComponentId == p.ComponentId)    // include rows with matching ComponentId
    ).ToList();

return result;    // contains list of ComponentProfiles
```

Comment: This worked. The best solution so far. I just needed the componentProfiles

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

```
var components = context.Components
     .Include("ComponentsProfiles") // I believe it is plural, but you need to check.
     .Where(i => i.BusinessEntityId == businessEntityId )
     .ToList();
```

You then loop through components, and get the corresponding component profiles.

```
foreach(var component in components) {
   var componentProfiles = component.ComponentsProfiles;
}
```

FYI: It is better to have unique identifier column in ComponentProfile table.

Comment: The last part component does not contain component profiles.. so component.ComponentProfiles is not working

Comment: it retrieves all components with the business entity id

Comment: Do you mean - `var communityProfiles = context.ComponentProfiles.Where(p => p.Components.BusinessEntityId == businessEntityId).ToList();`?

Answer (score 1):

I renamed your initial variable to be plural, since it returns multiple rows:

```
var components = context.Components.Where(i => i.BusinessEntityId == businessEntityId).ToList();
```

Now you can group your components by `ComponentId` so they are distinct:

```
var componentGroups = components.GroupBy(c => c.ComponentId);
```

Now you can combine the components that have each `ComponentId` with the `ComponentProfile`:

```
var componentProfiles = componentGroups.Select(cg => new { Components = cg.Select(c => c), Profile = context.ComponentProfiles.Single(cp => cp.ComponentId == cg.Key) });
```

So `componentProfiles` is an anonymous object that combines the list of `Components` rows with what I enforced is the single `ComponentProfiles` row that they use.

Comment: This is not working. It only retrieves one component profile and returns componentid as 0 for some reason

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work out from all the pieces answered:

```
 try
        {
            var context = GetCoreDbEntityContext(businessEntityId);
            var components = context.Components.Where(i => i.BusinessEntityId == businessEntityId).ToList();
            var componentIdsDistinct = components.Select(c => c.Id).Distinct();

            foreach (var componentId in componentIdsDistinct)
            {
                var componentProfile = context.ComponentProfiles.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ComponentId == componentId);
                if (componentProfile != null)
                {
                    result.Add(componentProfile.Map<Libraries.Entities.ComponentProfile>());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-to-many relation between `Profiles` and `Components`:

- Every `Component` has exactly one `Profile` (using a foreign key with a rather confusing name. I'll use `ProfileId`);
- Every `Profile` may be used by zero or more `Components`.

Because one `Profile` may be used by several `Components`, there may be several 'Components' with the same foreign key value 'ProfileId`

> I want to fetch All Component for a specific Business entity Id
>   and then display all component Profiles for those Component ids

So given a `businessEntityId`, you need to find all `Components` with this `businessEntityId`. Once you've got these components, you can find the `Profiles` that belong to these components. As said, several `Components` may belong to the same `Profile`, so you'll have to use `Distinct` to remove duplicates.

```
var result = MyComponents
    // keep only the components with businessEntityId
    .Where(component => component.BusinessEntityId == businessEntitId)
    .Join(MyProfiles,                      // Join with Profiles
        component => component.ProfileId,  // from every component take the foreign key
        profile => profile.Id,             // from every profile take the primary key
        (component, profile) =>            // when they match
            profile)                       // keep the matching profile
    .Distinct()                            // and remove duplicates
```